How To automatically detect headphone connection using react-native expo
I am creating a mobile application using react-native expo for our organization to play mp3 files, so the files are our property and should not be shared with others, by recording it from outside app.so it should be only played when the headphones are connected.

Here is a solution with what I know.
Try making a hook state connection to check when the headset is connected or not.
Write a function to check if headphones are connected by getting the current audio mode using Audio.getAudioModeAsync().
Add a listener for changes in the audio mode using AudioMode.addListener(). When the audio mode changes, call the function for audio connection to update the state accordingly.
Update the use state variable to update based on the headphone connection status, and the UI displays whether headphones are connected or disconnected.

Sir I did this
const checkHeadphones = async () => {     try {       const audioMode = await Audio.getAudioModeAsync();       setHeadphonesConnected(audioMode.outputType === 'HEADPHONES');     } catch (error) {       console.error('Error getting audio mode:', error);     }   };
but show me this error
ERROR  Error getting audio mode: [TypeError: _expoAv.Audio.getAudioModeAsync is not a function (it is undefined)]

Ok, what this means is that the function is not defined, which is probably because of the access of the expo audio API. This also indicates that the data is not coming properly. I believe it has to be the way you have configured the API.

Thanks, but still I have problem
